# Get file content via PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have an website. Let's call it `http://www.domain.com`. Now, on this domain.com I want to display the file contents of `http://www.adserversite.com/ads.php`. How can I do that with cURL or another method? I don't want to use `iframe`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of the **Related Section**. Please do research before asking questions that have been asked already or are easily answerable by googling.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents` as Petr says, but you need to activate [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in your `php.ini` and perhaps your hosting do not allow you to change this.

If you prefer to use CURL instead of `file_get_contents`, try this code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.adserversite.com/ads.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Although true and completely accurate, it might be useful for full disclosure that using cURL has the requirement of having the cURL extension installed, where `allow_url_fopen` is on by default ;)

Comment: You are right, file_get_contents is preferible, but I encountered problems in the past with shared hostings.

Comment: With PHP 7 I am having trouble with both approaches allow_url_fopen is on an curl is installed.

Comment: Is there any way to read the data line by line? I seem to get a big mess of text read from the file.

Answer (score 12):

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.adserversite.com/ads.php');
```

Who needs curl for this simple task?

Comment: Note: if `allow_url_fopen` is "On" in php.ini, which may not be true on some shared hostings, like @m4t1t0 mentioned already. I personally faced several times situation when curl was installed, but `allow_url_fopen` was disabled.

Comment: Also note that file_get_contents is much slower then cURL! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004805/file-get-contents-or-curl-in-php/24954327#24954327

Comment: Also note that curl does properly check for SSL certificates by default - PHP only does the right thing since version 5.6, and cannot support SubjectAlternativeName fields in earlier versions.