# PHP: easiest way to read a remote file into a string

Tags: php, file, url

This seems like it would be the most basic thing, maybe so basic that no one bothers to mention it. I've learned all the basic PHP syntax and some functions like `fread()` and `fopen()`, but I can't find a good way to download a URL into a string. Right now my best attempt is:

```
$someFile = fopen("http://www.pastats.com/report/winners?start=1386916400&duration=86400", r);
$someData = fread($someFile, filesize("http://www.pastats.com/report/winners?start=1386916400&duration=86400") );
```

but it doesn't work because apparently `filesize` doesn't work if I don't have write permissions. I know there's got to be a really simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your permissions are set correctly (`allow_url_fopen` set to true), which it sounds like it is, then [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents) is your best bet. Otherwise you'll want to [use PHP's `cURL` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl).