# CURL timeout - Server Issue? Other Domain URL works

Tags: php, apache

The following code works when I use the URL to some external like stackoverflow in the example below

```
<?php
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
echo $data;
curl_close($curl);
```

The problem is when I call my local server url

$url="https://example.com/apiv1.php?test=abc&pet=ss"; It throws error

```
cURL Error #:Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds
```

My API code looks like this

```
<?php
echo "ACCEPTED";
?>
```

And please I tried increasing the PHP timeout, I tried setting the timeout in CURL as well nothing works

Sometimes it throws an error

```
cURL Error #:Failed to connect to mydomain.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get file content via PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl)

Comment: Can you access `https://example.com/apiv1.php?test=abc&pet=ss` in your browser?

Comment: there might be no server listening at `:443` - or the self-signed certificate might not match `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @aynber Yes, I can access in the browser and in postman as well

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried with HTTP as well the URL works in the browser and show the response

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
echo $data;
curl_close($curl);
```